# Delphi, ADO, MySQL: checking whether an empty set was returned

Tags: mysql, delphi, ado

The version of Delphi is 7.

I'm sending a query to a MySQL database. What can be returned is either a set of data rows or simply an empty set. Nothing unusual. But I have no idea how to make a checking mechanism that will check whether it is a set of data or an empty set.

Here's some code:

```
var
    Q: TADOQuery;
begin
    Q := TADOQuery.Create(self);
    Q.Connection := ADOConnection;

    Q.SQL.Add('CALL get_shopping_cart_list()'); // Call stored procedure
    Q.Open;                                     // Send query and get some
                                                // results back
    // PSEUDOCODE
    // IF get_shopping_cart_list() RETURNS A NON-EMPY SET THEN
    //     SHOW WHAT WE HAVE
    // ELSE
    //     SHOW A MESSAGE THAT SAYS 'EMPTY SET'

    Q.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on Delphi version it can be either

```
 if Q.IsEmpty then ...
```

or

```
 if Q.BOF and Q.EOF then ...
```

You can also dive into Microsoft ADO. As long as there are no multiple statements in your query, `Q.RecordSet.EOF` and `Q.RecordSet.BOF` should do.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms675787.aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms677539.aspx

---

Also please do not forget to guard memory management of errors.

```
 Q := TADOQuery.Create;
 try
    .... do this or that ....
    .... do this or that ....
    .... do this or that ....
 finally
    Q.free;
 end;
```

Comment: @SirRufo No. ADO claims it may just return -1. Also this is SP. To count all records in uni-directional cursor you have to actually fetch them all, pass through the network, and then cache in client's RAM. I guess both server and client have better things to do. Using RecordCount is a common topic of people moved from DBF/CSV/Paradox to SQL, but that is generally a bad advice for any DB access library, including OLE DB. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ms676701.aspx

Comment: Sounds like the condition Q.RecordCount > 0 will do. What do you think?

Comment: IsEmpty sounds like the best approach so far.

Comment: @Mikhail As i told above RecordCount is very bad habit in SQL. But if you need to replace one boolean function call with slow and unreliable integer function call, and the comparisons where you may just mistype something wrong like `RecordCount >= 0` or `RecordCount > i0` or whatever random error you may do... Well, at least that would be easy to fix later to release next version :-D